# Find Lebesgue measure of $\limsup A_n \cap B_n$ if $m(\limsup A_n)=m(\liminf B_n)=1$,

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $m$ be the lebesgue measure on $X=[0,1]$. if $m(\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow{\infty}} {A_n})=1$ and $m(\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow{\infty}} {B_n})=1$, prove that $m(\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow{\infty}} {A_n \cap B_n})=1$. 
I got stuck after I expanded the $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow{\infty}} {A_n \cap B_n}$ by definition.

Comment: Observe that $\limsup (A_n\cap B_n)$ contains $(\liminf B_n)\cap(\limsup A_n)$.

Comment: @Etienne Another question, how did you get your observation?

Comment: I just asked myself : when are you sure to be in $\limsup (A_n\cap B_n)$, i.e. in $A_n\cap B_n$ for infinitely many $n$? And quickly realized that this definitely happens if you are in $A_n$ for infinitely many $n$ and in $A_n$ for all but finitely many $n$.

Comment: @Etienne Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses the hint given in *Etienne*'s comment. Let $\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n=A,\liminf_{n\to\infty}B_n=B,\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n\cap B_n=E$.

> $A\cap B\subseteq E$

$$\begin{align}
&x\in A\cap B\implies \color{blue}{(x\in B)}\land \color{red}{(x\in A)}\\
\implies&\color{blue}{\left(x\in\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty\bigcap_{n=k}^\infty B_n\right)}\land\color{red}{\left(x\in\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty A_n\right)}\\
\implies&\color{blue}{\left(\exists q: x\in\bigcap_{n=q}^\infty B_n\right)}\land\color{red}{\left(x\in\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty A_n\;\forall\;k\right)}\\
\implies&\color{blue}{(\;\exists q: x\in B_{n}\;\forall\;n\ge q\;)}\land\color{red}{(\text{ given }k\;\exists p\ge k: x\in A_{p} )}\\
\implies&\color{blue}{(\;\exists q: x\in B_{n}\;\forall\;n\ge q\;)}\land \color{red}{(\text{ given }k\;\exists p\ge \max(k,q): x\in A_{p} )}\\
\implies&\text{ given }k\;\exists p\ge k: x\in A_p\cap B_p\\
\implies& x\in\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty(A_n\cap B_n)\qquad\forall\;k\in\mathbb{N}\\
\end{align}$$

Assuming $E$ is Lebesgue-measurable we have

> $m(E)\ge 1$

$$\begin{align}
& A\cap B\subseteq E\\
\implies& X\setminus E\subseteq X\setminus (A\cap B)=(X\setminus A)\cup(X\setminus B)\\
\implies& m(X\setminus E)\le m((X\setminus A)\cup(X\setminus B))\le m(X\setminus A)+m(X\setminus B)\\
\implies& m(X)-m(E)\le 2m(X)-m(A)-m(B)\\
\implies& m(E)\ge m(A)+m(B)-m(X)=1+1-1=1
\end{align}$$

> $m(E)\le 1$

$$E\subseteq X\implies m(E)\le m(X)=1$$

Comment: Thank you! I will try to redo it and you and Etienne mentioned.